# Adding date to a date input field Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, input

I have some logic that i simplified in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r7vyjg4h/ and that works.

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="line in lines">
    <div style="display: inline-block">
      {{line.id}}
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block">
      <input type="text" ng-model="line.date" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" ng-click="update()" value="update" />
</div>
```

js:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.lines = [{
        id:"1",
        date: new Date()
      },{
        id:"2",
        date: new Date()
      },{
        id:"3",
        date: new Date()
      }
      ];
      var newDates = [{id:"1", date: new Date('10-10-2010 10:10:10')}, {id:"3", date: new Date('11-11-2011 11:11:11')}];

      $scope.update = function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < newDates.length;i++){
            for(var j = 0; j < $scope.lines.length; j++){
              if($scope.lines[j].id == newDates[i].id){
                  $scope.lines[j].date = newDates[i].date;
              }
            }
          }
      }
```

What it does it picks some dates from a web request and are supposed to add it to the right boxes in an ng-repeat. So far it still works out correct.

But when i change the input type from **text** to **date**, nothing happens. The values i picks out is correct but the date elements does not update.

http://jsfiddle.net/vd347sfa/

What am i missing here? Am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML-5 date input specification relies on RFC3339 section 5.6 which specifies a date format equal to `yyyy-MM-dd`. (Note: that is exactly the error message in the console when you run your jsfiddle). You just have to supply the date string in the correct format: http://jsfiddle.net/yxkvm0zm/1/

Comment: Just an aside: [Google's Quick FAQs on `input[type=date]` in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome) explicitly states "When setting the `input.value` programmatically, the value accepts only `yyyy-mm-dd` style regardless of the presentation format for both the initial value and the JavaScript injected value". (I tripped over this myself some time ago ...).

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not reflecting in date input field is because the formatting.

The date input field is looking for the format `mm/dd/yyyy` and you are providing `10-10-2010 10:10:10` in this format.

You can use the function to convert the date into `toISOString()` format and it should do the trick.

There you go check this Solution :

```
 var newDates = [{id:"1", date: new Date('10-10-2010 10:00:00').toISOString().substring(0, 10)},{id:"2", date: new Date('10-10-2010 11:00:00').toISOString().substring(0, 10)}, {id:"3", date: new Date('11-11-2011 12:00:00').toISOString().substring(0, 10)}];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vd347sfa/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the date and time in proper format. the correct way to do this is:

```
var newDates = [{id:"1", date: new Date('2010', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10')}, 
{id:"3", date: new Date('2011', '11', '11', '11','11','11')}];
```

the format is:

```
new Date('yyyy', 'mm', 'dd', 'hh', 'mm', 'ss');
```